# jquery change text on div

Tags: jquery

I need to change only the text inside the div, where there is other elements inside it. I tried the `text` method but it changed the whole content of the div.

Example div:

```
<div class="mydiv">
MY TEXT HERE
<ul>
   <li>BLAH</li>
   <li>BLAH</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is what I have tried for now: `$(".mydiv").text("MY NEW TEXT");`

Comment: Put a span around your text and just modify the span.

Comment: can't do that, unless there's a way I can encapsulate the text with span using jquery..hehe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$.fn.extend({
    text2: function(t){
        return this.each(function(a,b){
            $(b).contents().map(function(c,d){
                return (d.nodeType === 3 ? d : null);
            }).get(0).data = t;
        });
    }
});
```

There's my solution. Only effects the **first** text node found within the selector, then replaces it with the supplied text. Using this, `$('.mydiv').text2('MY NEW TEXT');` should work [flawlessly](http://jsfiddle.net/dz4kB/).

Answer (score 3):

Put the text of the div into another element, then select and replace the element with jQuery.

```
$('.mydiv div.text').text("MY NEW TEXT")

<div class="mydiv">
<div class="text">MY TEXT HERE</div>
<ul>
   <li>BLAH</li>
   <li>BLAH</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
$(".mydiv").html("MY NEW TEXT");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/mtH27/

Comment: What?! I thought .html altered the entire contents of the element. It doesn't touch child elements I guess?

Comment: By the way, you can encapsulate that text inside a '<p>' tag or span and just target the text (or add a special class). [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/mtH27/1/)

Comment: I tried your demo, but it removes the list Blah Blah..and I can't encapsulate..unless there is a way to encapsulate it through jquery hehe

Comment: @mrtsherman the **.html()** method does alter the entire content of an element, you just have to target correctly if you just want to alter an specific block of an element. (see my second demo that i posted on the comments, there i target just the text on the div)

Comment: @jovhenni19 so the text is not enclosed in any way? not even in a paragraph tag? just plain text?

Comment: As noted, this does not work for the problem as stated, where the text is the un-encapsulated content of a div. html() removes all child elements of the div and substitutes the passed argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for that particular situation: http://jsfiddle.net/mtH27/10/

```
$(".mydiv")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "Is this what you want?"
```

Comment: This worked for the case where the text to replace was the first child node in the div. I ended up using this approach for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

This method is easier: instead of trying to work with text node manipulation, remove all tags from the element, replace the inner text, and append the tags:

http://jsfiddle.net/NFEgE/1/

This will get a lot more complicated if you have multiple text nodes to worry about.

Comment: @jovhenni19 is the css being changed by jquery?