# Grab some text from a markup string using jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have the following markup:

```
<span>
Some text blalablalalbal<br/><br/>
"You are Awesome" <br/><br/>
----What can I do for you?<br/><br/>
</span>
```

Now I want to hide first line and modify the last line.

How can I grab those text using jQuery?

**Note:**

1: There are multiple instances of similar code-block but with different text. So I won't be able to hardcode. I am wondering if I can split it using 
 tags somehow?

2: If it can be done in server-side code in C#, that is fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play around with [textnodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textnode) doing [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592074/jquery-change-text-on-div/7592172#7592172).

---

**Update**

```
var $nodes = $('span').contents().map(function(a,b){
    return (b.nodeType===3?b:null);
});

// hide first line
$($nodes.get(0)).wrap('<span style="display:none;" />');
$nodes.get(2).data = "foo";
```

[Working example of what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ub5U/).

Comment: Thanks. It works but I already came up with something similar.

Comment: I used `(b.nodeType===Node.TEXT_NODE?b:null);` instead of hard coding the value 3, easier to understand. Looked at this for help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType

Answer (score 0):

CSS has :first-line and :last-line modifiers.

Try:

```
span:first-line {
  display: none;
}
```

Use jQuery with selector to modify last line:

```
var content = $('span:last-line').html();
content += " - Modified";
$('span:last-line').html(content);
```

Comment: I haven't tested the above code, but it should work in theory! :D

Comment: I don’t think jQuery has a :first-line or :last-line selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the line breaks and modify the array:

```
var elm = $('span'),
    lines = elm.html().split('<br>');

lines.shift(); // removes the first
lines[lines.length-3] += '-modified'; // modify the last

elm.html(lines.join('<br>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put the three lines in three different spans with ids.
Something like:

```
<span>
<span id="sentence1">Some text blalablalalbal</span><br/><br/>
<span id="sentence2">"You are Awesome" </span><br/><br/>
<span id="sentence3">----What can I do for you?</span><br/><br/>
</span>
```

And hiding the first sentence with jquery:

```
$("span#sentence1").hide();
```